# Setting driver context to webview in AWS device farm

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, mobile, device

Any idea how to set driver context to webview in AWS device farm.  ?
I have tried like this ,Its works fine with Local Appium server. and samsung S3 device.
But its throwing an error in AWS device farm .

Comment: `Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
        driver.context(contextName);
    }`
}

Comment: share code and logcat..........

Comment: The code seems correct. Which Android version are you trying to run it against?